# Delphi XE5 Firemonkey TStringGrid OnClick event

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, tstringgrid

I have a very strange problem with Delphi Firemonkey TStringGrid on Android. It looks like that events on TStringGrid are triggered differently on windows and android platform. 
For example: in windows firemonkey application I have a string grid with a few columns. TStringGrid is set as read only. OnClick event I have the following code:

```
TStringGrid(Sender).Cells[TStringGrid(Sender).ColumnIndex,TStringGrid(Sender).Selected] := 'result';
```

Android application has exactley the same code OnClick event

```
TStringGrid(Sender).Cells[TStringGrid(Sender).ColumnIndex, TStringGrid(Sender).Selected] := 'result';
```

When I run windows application and click on string grid cell it becomes selected and then ‘result’ is written in the cell.

windows before click

[image]

windows after click

[image]

When I run android application and do click (tap) what happens is that ‘result’ is written in previously selected cell, and after that cell where I did click becomes selected.

android before click

[image]

android after click

[image]

I am not sure is this a bug in Firemonkey or expected behavior. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Are you aware of the Embarcadero forums (the maker of delphi)? https://forums.embarcadero.com/forum.jspa?forumID=522

Comment: Yes, and I am forum member since 1999. Thank you very much for your suggestion but your comment doesn't help. Stackoverflow has much more available users that are willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TGrid is not a supported control on mobile so you should avoid using it. The best alternative is probably a TListBox with a custom style.

Comment: Thank you Mike. For what am I doing now this is very useful information, but I am not very happy with that fact.
Do you know by any chance what is causing different behaviour in events on android and windows, despite that control is not supported?

Comment: Sorry, no. I've never dug into what the details are of the differences between desktop and mobile for this. You could try tracing through the FireMonkey sources but it could well be a difficult journey.

Answer (score 0):

It might a threading issue. But I'm not so sure you are using the best event handler. If you are trying to update the cell that is being selected, then I would advice you handle the TStringGrid.OnSelChanged event. This event is fired after cell selection has been changed.

Beware though... it is not strictly fired by mouse clicks (or finger taps). If you have some sort of keyboard attached to the Android device, or on a desktop platform, it will also fire when you use arrow keys and other means. I think you get what I mean... but then maybe that is just what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. Unfortunatley I tried to use OnSelChanged but again it doesn't behave as I expect it should. For example if selected cell is [1, 1], and I click/tap/whatever on cell [2, 2], event will be triggered twice. First it will trigger on column change, than on row change. In that case I have 'result' written in cell [1, 2] and [2, 2]. It is weird but this is how it works.
I tested this it works the same on windows and android.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be some other way. Handling the mouse event (OnMouseUp, OnMouseDown) is possible, but a bit complex and probably unnecessary.

Comment: It's a scoreboard for android card game. We can take other game like yahtzee/yamb for example. You can throw dices and depending on your strategy you can select where to write score. When you click on cell, if it is allowed to write score in that cell, then program will calculate and write your score into selected cell. I don't want this to be entered with keyboard.
Actually what bothers me the most (if this is not a bug) is the fact that events on windows and android on firemonkey framework sometimes works different. Is there any documentation that covers this topic?

Comment: I don't think there is any documentation. You see... the FireMonkey code is actually the same (I was looking at it before). This has probably something to do with how system events are hooked and/or threaded.
Getting back to your problem. TStringGrid.OnClick is not the correct event. It doesn't even tell you which cell has been clicked. You need a Cell event.
What I'd do is to derive a custom component from TStringGrid that uses a custom class of TTextCell to handle cells... and hook up to the OnEnter event of that. Not much code... but some confidence with component design is required.

Comment: ...or... come to think of it... you could throw away the grid altogether and work with a TGridLayout and just use TEdits and/or TLabels and/or whatever other fancy control you need. That way you have complete control on any and all events. And no custom controls are required :)

Comment: I am already handling TTextCell to set font and format on it. 
Thanks. That is a one possible solution, and TGridLayout is second,
or I can use TGrid with generic column and use whatever control I like. I am still looking for a reasonable explanation why events works like this.