# firemonkey -unable to compile (Exception class Illegal instruction (4)) for android with arm 7 rev5 neon supported

Tags: android, ios, delphi, exception, firemonkey

I made simple application using firedac and interbase database, but when try to compile it shows error "Exception class Illegal instruction (4)" without any further information.

I am using android ndk v.r10b and no luck for latest version (ndk vr10e) other, connected to samsung galaxy v plus series(arm 7 rev5) with neon supported.

here is the screenshot of the project :

[image]

note: i can compile any other application for android without using firedac / interbase, problem occurs when using firedac / interbase

Comment: I suspect that the device is not supported for application development - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development

Comment: @RBA it is supported, device is using android 4.4. and api level 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently i found the solution from here : [Delphi XE5 Firemonkey TStringGrid OnClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22975120/delphi-xe5-firemonkey-tstringgrid-onclick-event?rq=1)

After change into listview instead of TGrid, the application works fine